# How to connect to a new server if the main one is closed

Tags: java, android

I made a controller app, that send a string to the server and the server will push the corresponding button. But i want to make a backup server so if the main is closed the client will connect to the other server automatically.
Here is a peace of code from the client side:

```
try{
    s= new Socket("ip",7800);
    pw= new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    pw.write(message);
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    s.close();
}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

```
//sending the string
MessageSender messageSender = new MessageSender();
messageSender.execute("S");
```

The backup server is the same but in another port, how can i connect to that if the connection to the main one is lost? Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionException will be thrown typically, the connection is refused remotely (e.g., no process is listening on the remote address/port)

you can catch ConnectionException or its base class SocketException  or even its base IOException, when this event occurs and fallback on backup server.

```java
 try{

            s= new Socket("ip",7800);
            pw= new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            pw.write(message);
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            s.close();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //fall back code
            s= new Socket("ip",7800);
            ....



        }
```

Note: You can re-factor the above code  and you can re-use the code in try block